# rush rebuild specify projects order

Tags: azure-devops, rush

I am using microsoft rush to build a mono-repo.
I have to build two projects - `tools-common` and `tools-backend`
`tools-backend` depends on `tools-common`.
`rush rebuild` works fine on the local machine.
But on azure devops, it tries to first build `tools-backend` and it fails for not finding `tools-common`.

My questions are.

1. Why rush on azure devops fails to detect the order?
2. How can I ensure that it picks up `tools-common` before `tools-backend` ?

Comment: I solved it by adding `tools-common` in devDependencies as well. Earlier it was in peerDependencies only.
It seems that rush does not try to resolve peerDependencies. 
So if we have a local project, we should add it both in dev and peer dependencies.

Why it worked on my local machine was it held copy of tools-common dist from previous run.
It would not work on local either when I totally purged and cleaned dist.

This is what I have found.
But any better explanation is welcome.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your sharing, you could convert your comment into an answer, it could help other community members who get the same issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding `tools-common` in `devDependencies` as well. Earlier it was in `peerDependencies` only.
It seems that rush does not try to resolve `peerDependencies`.
So if we have a local project, we should add it both in dev and peer dependencies.

Why it worked on my local machine was it held copy of `tools-common` dist from previous run.
It would not work on local either
This is what I have found.
But any better explanation is welcome.